# if else statement within formview

Tags: asp.net, formview

i have a FormView, it renders fields from a SQLServer database but also much static text specific to the database value I get. I dont know if this can be done in the code behind and put all this in a function . I put it in my formview

```
<ItemTemplate>

<% If Eval("Feature1") = "Yes" Then %>

 <%# Eval("Username") %> <p>A lot of text</p>

 <% elseIf Eval("Feature1") = "No" Then %>

 <%# Eval("Username") %>
<p>A lot of different text</p>

 <% End If %>

</ItemTemplate>
```

If I do the code above I get error message:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control. Can this be done within
>   the formview?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you missing the <asp:formview id="formview1" runat="server"></asp:formview> tags around your code, or did you leave them out intentionally?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataBinder.Eval` as follows:

```
<% if (DataBinder.Eval(formview.DataItem, "First") == "Yes") { %>
    <p>A lot of text</p>
<% } else { %>
    <p>A lot of different text</p>
<% } %>
```

If you have any postback, you must store the `DataItem` somewhere and use that as a parameter of the `DataBinder.Eval` instead because it becomes null.

Answer (score 0):

Your if logic should be in the code behind, in the databound event of your control.

Each row will fire this event, and you can then edit how the row should look based on the data.

```
protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Hi Thaks. I knew this. I just wanted to ask if there was a better way to present the heavy text involved in code behind.

Comment: IMO, this is the best and preferred way.  No reason to recreate the wheel.